# Sonarqube Apache2 Reverse Proxy configuration

Tags: sonarqube, apache2, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-16.04, sonarqube-ops

I am trying to set up SonarQube behind an Apache2 reverse proxy.  Getting a 404 when i hit http://server/sonar.  Server is running Ubuntu 16.04

My configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sonar.conf:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName        server
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Proxy http://localhost:9000/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /sonar    http://localhost:9000/sonar
    ProxyPassReverse  /sonar    http://localhost:9000/sonar
</Virtualhost>
```

Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: Did you enable name based virtual hosting?

Comment: I have a similar problem. My question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68125324/apache2-httpd-reverse-proxy-not-working-with-sonarqube-server-on-docker-compos